# How can I hide a list component when it contains no items?

Tags: apache-flex, dataprovider

I have a List of items which is based on the contents of the "category" that a user selects

When the user changes selection, I change the `dataProvider` of the list be be the contents of the current category.

Sometimes the list contains items, sometimes it does not

Is there a way of hiding the list when it has no items?

I know that I could do this when setting the `dataProvider`, but it seems like there should be an event or something else that I could be using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
visible="{myList.dataProvider.length>0}"
includeInLayout="{myList.dataProvider.length>0}"
```

where "myList" is the id of your List component.

Answer (score 0):

My first solution to this was to override set dataProvider:

```
override public function set dataProvider(value:IList):void {
    super.dataProvider = value;
    this.setVisible(value.length > 0);
}
```

This did work, however Robusto's solution works also and is preferable IMO.